# Testing internationalisations / translations

Tags: android, internationalization, translation

Is there a way to easily test out my translations for an Android app on a developer phone, if your phone's Settings->Languages menu doesn't have those? For example, to test translations for a desktop Linux application, I can run it like so:

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 ./myapp
```

Is there a similar setting or trigger to do this for an Android app?

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of good information at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Bottom line: If your developer phone doesn't support the locale you want to test, it's not worth the effort to make it work.  Instead, do your testing on an emulator.

The emulator has a large selection of built-in locales.  If you can't find the one you want in there, look for an application called "Custom Locale" installed in the emulator.

Run "Custom Locale", and define the locale you want to use.  It's really quite easy.